# Calendar module

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type ("events") that has a date field inside it ("field_e_date"); I want to show on a page some nodes of this content type in calendar format.

Assuming I create a view of style calendar type, I want to display on http://example.com/user/uid 5 events added by this user.

Which exact arguments do I need to pass to the view?

Comment: CCK is not in Drupal 7. Also, if you have too much trouble with Calendar, you could try the [FullCalendar module](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar).

Comment: hey..since you are the maintainer of the module can you help me that using your module how would the above thing be done..i just need to know what arguments and other configuration are required?

Comment: I would not create a view that is viewed at `user/<uid>` because it would override the user profile page. A view cannot be attached to a page generated from another module; you need Panels, and create a user profile panels that include a calendar view.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, that is why in my answer, I suggested creating a block. Also, not sure why my answer was downvoted, since I was explicitly asked for help.

Comment: i did not downvote..i upvoted you..

Comment: @tim.plunkett I am referring to the question asked by ayush. About the answer, an answer that suggests to use module Y, when the module is asking how to do something with module X is not the answer to the question asked from the OP. Module Y doesn't automatically create the view the OP is asking for, nor would it create a view that is attached to the page created by another module; the OP should follow similar steps to get the desired views, whenever he uses module X, or Y. Finally, when you are referring to a module you are developing, you should at least declare that.

Answer (score 4):

Download and install [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar).
Create a new block view with the Format: FullCalendar, and the Style: FullCalendar (Fields).

Add the date field you want to display, set the pager to only display 5 events. Set the Contextual Filter (argument) to User: ID, provide a default value of "User ID from URL".

Save the view, and place the block on the user page. Should work fine.